# How to use timer to stop/ start animation?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a class which effects an animation by the parameters given.
Like this `Rotate r = new Rotate(250)`, but i cant use the timer  correctly, I know there are similar questions, but I cant solve the problem anyway. I can do it to rotate, but cant determine when to stop. Here is basic code:

```
public class Rotate   extends JPanel  {

    public Rotate(int angle){

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g ) {

        int drawLocationX = 55;
        int drawLocationY = 111;
        BufferedImage image = LoadImage("cutted.png");
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(drawLocationX,drawLocationY);
        at.rotate(angle, image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(image, at, null);

        revalidate();
        repaint();      
    }

    BufferedImage LoadImage (String FileName){
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(FileName));
        }
        catch(IOException e){

        }
        return img;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never:

1. Read the image in a painting method. It is inefficient to read the image every time you want to paint the component. Read the image in the constructor of your class and save the image as an instance variable.
2. Invoke revalidate() or repaint() in a painting method. This will cause an infinite loop.

> I am trying to create a class which effects an animation

Then you need to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation. When the Timer fires you need to change the angle. So in your class you might need to add a couple of methods like getAngle() and setAngle(...).

The setAngle() might look like:

```
public void setAngle(int angle)
{
    this.angle = angle;
    repaint();
}
```

So when the Timer fires you would simply invoke:

```
myPanel.setAngle( myPanel.getAngle() + 1 );
```

> but cant determine when to stop

Don't know what that means to you. Do you want to stop after 360 degrees or rotation. Then you need to keep a counter in the Timer code to stop that Timer after it fires 360 times.